# Unable to caching image data from canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, browser-cache

So I have a function that converts an image to grayscale.
It takes in an url for the origonal image, and an output canvas to put the output onto.
The function runs very quick on most browsers however very slow on mobile browsers (~3-4s for a 700x700 image). For this reason I want to cache (on the client) the grayscale image data, then when a request for the image comes multiple times, I want to serve up the cached grayscale data and not have to recalculate it.

I have whipped up a test on jsfiddle. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/RCkDX/4/
In the test page I display the origonal image at the top, I output the canvas that is used to do the calculation at the bottom and the two canvas' in the middle they should output the same as the bottom image (except with cached data).

At the moment I get a 'Uncaught TypeError: Type error', I think its because it doesnt seem to  like the cache data, I have tried moving things around, trying different methods but have not had any luck.

It is important that I do not use dataurls to cache as the android mobile browser I am using will display a little blue question mark icon at the moment (not the correct data on the canvas), so any option without dataurls would work.

Comment: Is you sure what losing of speed on mobile devices occurs because grayscale conversion function runs slow. May be you lost speed because mobile connection speed can be slower than desktop connection?

Comment: Its definitely not the image download speed, as I even have the images cached using Expires server-side header.

Comment: See updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/RCkDX/5/ Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Awesome thankyou so much! Post it as an answer and I will accept, It isn't obvious to me what the difference is that makes this work, would you be able to point it out? Also I see in your version there is no timeouts, the reason I had this in, is so that the UI doesn't freeze while doing the processing, is it the timers that stop my origonal code from working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jezternz, I think `'Uncaught TypeError: Type error'` in your code occurs because `readyCanvas` function called from `returnFunc` each time (no difference: cache exist or not); and inside `readyCanvas` *grayscaleCache[src]* can return *undefined* if no cache. In my code example ([jsfiddle.net/RCkDX/5](http://jsfiddle.net/RCkDX/5)) `readyCanvas` called from `returnFunc` only if *grayscaleCache[src]* is defined (cache is constructed and saved).
From my code removed `setTimeout`. Main reason: for simplify example.

If you need to build code with no blocking page (without freeze UI) you must provide more complex code for managing cache. For example:

- *grayscaleCache[src]* is *undefined* that mean *"no cache and cache is not under construction by any previous request"* - you need to start caching procedure;
- *grayscaleCache[src]* equals to *null* that mean *"cache is under construction by previous request"* - you dont need to start caching procedure, you must only wait (check with *setTimeout*) when cache is ready;
- *grayscaleCache[src]* is not *undefined* and not *null* - *"cache is ready"* - use cache.